# sendto() dgrams do not block for ENOBUFS on OSX

Tags: macos, sockets, unix, freebsd

This is more of a observation and also a suggestion for whats the best way to handle this scenario.

I have two threads one just pumps in data and another receives the data and does lot of work before sending it another socket. Both the threads are connected via a Domain socket. The protocol used here is UDP. I did not want to use TCP as it is stream based, which means if there is little space in the queue my data is split and sent. This is bad as Iam sending data that should not be split. Hence I used DGRAM. Interestingly when the send thread overwhelms the recv thread by pumping so much data, at some point the Domain socket buffer gets filled up and sendto() returns ENOBUFS. I was of the opinion that should this happen, sendto() would block until the buffer is available. This would be my desired behaviour. However this does not seem to be the case. I solve this problem in a rather weird way.

- CPU Yield method
  If I get ENOBUFS, I do a sched_yield(); as there is no pthread_yield() in OSX. After that I try to resend again. If that fails I keep doing the same until it is taken. This is bad as Iam wasting cpu cycles just doing something useless. I would love if sendto() blocked.
- Sleep method
  I tried to solve the same issue using sleep(1) instead of sched_yield() but this of no use as sleep() would put my process to sleep instead of just that send thread.

Both of them does not seem to work for me and Iam running out of options. Can someone suggest what is the best way to handle this issue? Is there some clever tricks Iam not aware of that can reduce unnecessary cpu cycles? btw, what the man page says about sentto() is wrong, based on this discussion http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2004-January/005385.html

The Upd code in kernel:

```
The udp_output function in /sys/netinet/udp_usrreq.c, seems clear:

         /*
          * Calculate data length and get a mbuf
          * for UDP and IP headers.
          */
         M_PREPEND(m, sizeof(struct udpiphdr), M_DONTWAIT);
         if (m == 0) {
                 error = ENOBUFS;
                 if (addr)
                         splx(s);
                 goto release;
         }
```

Comment: How do you spawn the threads?  Actually, [sleep(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html) should work for POSIX threads.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why sendto() isn't blocking for you... but you might try calling this function before you each call to sendto():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

// Won't return until there is space available on the socket for writing
void WaitUntilSocketIsReadyForWrite(int socketFD)
{
   fd_set writeSet;
   FD_ZERO(&writeSet);
   FD_SET(socketFD, &writeSet);
   if (select(socketFD+1, NULL, &writeSet, NULL, NULL) < 0) perror("select");
}
```

Btw how big are the packets that you are trying to send?

Comment: Actually, Jeremy as I understand BSD based systems do not block on sendto() where as Linux and Solaris does. Select wont work here as in case of UDP there is no send buffer queue which is available in TCP hence select will not know about no buff. It will always allow but will fail with ENOBUFS. The kernel code for UDP is given below

Comment: It looks like for UDP on BSD and OSX sendto() will not block. Its wrongly mentioned in the man pages. Even select() cannot help. This is a very interesting discussion to read about the same issue http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2004-January/005369.html

Comment: Hmm, I use select() to limit the send() rate on non-blocking UDP sockets under OSX and that seems to work for me... of course it doesn't prevent packets from being dropped later on (e.g. at the network switch), but it does make it so my program sends out the UDP packets at the rate the outgoing-UDP-buffer can accept them.  For you case you might want to just byte the bullet and use TCP with some framing logic (e.g. send a "packet-size" header followed by the data in the "packet", so that the receiver can read the header first and know how many bytes to fill into a buffer before processing it)

Comment: Ha, I just ran into this same issue myself (when trying to send 92MB of data across a UDP-multicast socket over the loopback device under MacOS/X).  :(

Comment: For now I'm going to try to handle it by just checking for ENOBUFS and ignoring it (i.e.  looping back to select()).  Hopefully that won't cause too much busy-looping...

Answer (score 0):

sendto() on OS X is really nonblocking (that is M_DONTWAIT flag for). 
I suggest you to use stream based connection and just receive the whole data on the other side by using MSG_WAITALL  flag of the `recv` function. If your data has strict structure than it would be simple, just pass the correct size to the `recv`. If not than just send some fixed-size control packet first with the size of the next chunk of data and then the data itself. On the receiver side you would be wait for control packet of fixed size and than the data of size from control packet.